# Cannot create a link to Notepad++ in Cygwin

Tags: windows, notepad++, cygwin

I am trying to make a link to Notepad++ in Cygwin but I face the following error:

```
KD@HPi7 /home/kd/ns-allinone-2.35
$ ln /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe np
ln: failed to create hard link ‘np’: File exists

KD@HPi7 /home/kd/ns-allinone-2.35
$ np
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'
```

I have no clue why it issues the error because the path I entered for Notepad++ is what auto-completing via Tab key gives me in Cygwin command line. So, where might the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Where might the problem be?

> ln /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe np

The above command will not work as you also need to escape `(` and `)` that have a special meaning to bash.

- Bash sees the `(` as introducing a list of commands.
- Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a subshell to be created, and each of the commands in list to be executed in that subshell. Since the list is executed in a subshell, variable assignments do not remain in effect after the subshell completes.
- Bash tries to execute `x86`

The following should work:

```
ln /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)Notepad++/notepad++.exe np
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [brackets](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html) - Using parenthesis to group and expand expressions.
- [quoting](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-quoting.html) - Escape Characters, delimiters and Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

i just used an alias

`alias np="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"`